# React Context creates troubles with Apollo applied through compose

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I'm using React Context to communicate between components (actions)

Context.Consumer resides inside the return() part of a component and as such doesn't provide props to the component (unless Consumer is put in parent component but then we're back to the badness of props drilling)

Apollo client is applied by Apollo's compose() to that the result is available in component props but more importantly, *a change in props leads to Apollo refetch*

Using Context, this automatic refetch pathway is broken and I see no other way but to bring the whole GraphQl document into the component (after Context.Consume) to manually do a refetch when Context brings in action.

This is a radical change in pattern and I really wonder if I'm missing some big picture?

```
const Child = ({ gqlGetData }) => {
  if (gqlGetData.loading) return "..."
  const { componentData } = gqlGetData
  return (
    <AppControl.Consumer>
      {appControl => (
        <React.Fragment>
              ---component rendering logic here ---
              ---but needs also refetch logic and GraphQl document---
            )}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </AppControl.Consumer>
  )
}
```